# R - replace values in data frame using lookup table

Tags: r, lookup-tables

I was having some trouble lately trying to replace specific values in a data frame or matrix by using a lookup-table.

So this represents the original.data to be modified ...

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14
1  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
2  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   3   3 255 255 255 255
3  255 255 255 255 255   1   3   3   3   3   3 255 255 255
4  255 255   5   5   5   1   3   3   4   4   3 255 255 255
5  255   5   5   5   5   1   3   4   4   4   4 255 255 255
6  255   5   5   5   1   3   3   3   4   4   3   3 255 255
7  255 255   5   1   3   3   3   3   6   6   6   3 255 255
8  255 255   1   1   1   1   2   2   3   3   6   3 255 255
9  255 255   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3 255
10 255 255 255   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3 255
11 255 255 255   2   2   2   2   2   7   7   7   2 255 255
12 255 255 255   2   2   8   8   8   7 255 255 255 255 255
13 255 255 255 255   8   8 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
14 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

... and following may be the lookup.table (rows=1:9, column1="Sub", column2="Main"):

```
  Sub Main
1   1    1
2   2    2
3   3    3
4   4    4
5   5    5
6 255  255
7   6    3
8   7    2
9   8    2
```

The aim is to compare e.g.
`original.data[11,11]` [7] with `lookup.tabel[8,"Sub"]` [7]

... and write a new matrix 
`modified.data[11,11]` with `lookup.table[8,"Main"]` [2].
Until now all I came up with is using for-loops and an if-statement,

```
for (i in 1:ncol(original.data)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(lookup.table)){
    if (original.data[i,i]==lookup.table[j,1]){
      origingal.data[j,i]<-lookup.table[j,2]
    }
  }
}
```

which leads to

```
Error in origingal.data[j, i] <- lookup.table[j, 2] : 
  object 'origingal.data' not found
```

but i cannot figure out my errors in reasoning.

I'd love to get some hints.

Thanks

**\\\\\PROBLEM SOLVED**

```
for (i in 1:ncol(original.data)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(original.data)){
    for (x in 1:nrow(lookup.table)){
      if (original.data[j,i]==lookup.table[x,1]){
        original.data[j,i]<-lookup.table[x,2]
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

... works, but this is a much faster method:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(lookup.table)){
  c<-lookup.table[b,2]
  d<-lookup.table[b,3]
  original.data_modified[original.data == c] <- d
}
```

Comment: This is a typo error, the name of your data is `original.data` not `origingal`!! change it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

you can try :

```
# x the original.data (a matrix)
# y the lookup.table
x2 <- y[match(x, y[,1]),2]
dim(x2) <- dim(x)
table(x, x2)
     x2
x       1   2   3   4   5 255
  1    13   0   0   0   0   0
  2     0  22   0   0   0   0
  3     0   0  29   0   0   0
  4     0   0   0   8   0   0
  5     0   0   0   0  11   0
  6     0   0   4   0   0   0
  7     0   4   0   0   0   0
  8     0   5   0   0   0   0
  255   0   0   0   0   0 100
```