# Replace values by lookup table

Tags: r

For the longest time I have used code similar to the following in order to replace values in a vector based on a match in a "lookup" table. In this example, I am replacing values in the `input` object by corresponding values in the `key` object if they match any values in the second column of `key`.

```
key<-cbind(c("one","one","two","three","four","five"),c("one1","one11","two2","three3","over","over"))

input<-c("one1","one11","three","four","five")

input[which(!is.na(match(key[,2],input)))]<-key[!is.na(match(key[,2],input)),1]
```

Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this? The `merge` function does not seem to work. The method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475400/r-replace-values-in-data-frame-using-lookup-table) does not work when there is not a one-to-one match between `key` and `input`.

Comment: A much better way of doing this is with a join like `dplyr::left_join`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't quite correct:

- note that the `match(key[, 2], input)` in the index on the LHS is of length 6 (the length of `key`) not 5 (the length of `input`), and so `!is.na()` is of length 6 not 5, and `which(!is.na())` is an index into `key`, not into `input`.
- you additionally lose the **order** of the matches. by using `!is.na()` on the right hand side (it works in your example because the rows of `key` happen to be the same indices as the things to replace in `input`, and in the same order).

As an illustrative example, let's shuffle your `key`

```
key <- key[c(3,2,4,5,6,1), ]
input[which(!is.na(match(key[,2],input)))]<-key[!is.na(match(key[,2],input)),1]
input
[1] "one1"  "one"   "three" "four"  "five"  "one"
```

Note how your new `input` has 6 variables now, and the first `one1` wasn't replaced. Have a look at `match(key[,2], input)`, `is.na(...)` and `which(is.na(...))` to see why.

You need to use `match(input, key[,2])` which is non-NA when `input[i]` has a match in `key`, and has the value of the index into `key`. So now you can use `!is.na()` on the LHS to do the assignment, but don't use `!is.na()` on the right or you lose the indices of the matches in `key`.

```
m <- match(input, key[,2]) # 6 2 NA NA NA for the shuffled `key`
input[!is.na(m)] <- key[na.omit(m), 1]

# or a one-liner
input[!is.na(match(input, key[,2]))] <- key[na.omit(match(input, key[,2])), 1]
```

In terms of "more efficient", I reckon this is about as good as it gets - `merge` calls `match` internally anyway, so will most certainly be slower. It ain't "elegant", but it's fast.

The only improvement I see is to store the match first (like I have done above, storing the match in `m`) to avoid calling it twice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `na.omit`. My main issue is that it is difficult when reading through code to tell at a glance what is happening on these lines.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is hard to tell what is happening when reading back. That's why I usually go for the two-liner when doing this sort of thing, and I also tend to comment copiously when there's lots of `match(..)` going on.